# rendor google page using addon sdk page mod

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Hi i am working on a firefox extension which render the google search page (Such I want put some ads on the right side of search result ) it can be achieved by pagemod but  page must  be reloaded for apply the rules

myscript.js

```
   var eElement=document.getElementById("rhs");
   //self.port.emit("find","samsung");
   var newFirstElement= document.createElement("div");
   newFirstElement.setAttribute("style","height:400px;border: 3px solid #F0f0f0");
   newFirstElement.innerHTML="Put aids here";
   eElement.insertBefore(newFirstElement, eElement.firstChild);
```

main.js

```
   var data = require("sdk/self").data;
   var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
   pageMod.PageMod({
   include: "*.google.co.in",
   contentScriptFile: data.url("myscript.js"),
   attachTo: [ "existing","top"]
    });
```

How can I achieve this without page relaod. as i think when  search on google page the url is not reloaded. please help..

Answer (score 0):

> How can I achieve this without page relaod. as i think when search on google page the url is not reloaded. please help..

That's simple, you just need to hook into whichever custom event Google is using to trigger new searches, which may be one thing today and another thing tomorrow so you have to keep watching that.

As a fallback solution you could add keyboard event listeners to the search bar which google displays, if you need help doing that please ask another question.

Comment: Yeah You are right. But I want to modify google search page with the help of pagemod if I put a keyboard event listener for that page how it will capture by page mod.